# Windows 2008 RemoteAPP client disconnects within a matter of minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, remoteapp

I'm having an odd problem with Windows 2008 TS, and remote applications specifically.

The situation is as follows:

TS idle timeout is disabled via GPO

TS terminating disconnected sessions after 1hr (via GPO)

My users can log on to the Terminal server, and get a full desktop, OR via rdp files that give access to a few remote applications.

When a user connects to a full desktop, everything is fine and dandy, they will remain logged on indefinately, and when they disconnect the session is terminated after an hour.

however, when a user connects using a remote application link, the client seems to disconnect after only a few minutes of inactivity, when you click the window, the session reconnects.

EventID's on TS server:

4779: This event is generated when a user disconnects from an existing Terminal Services session, or when a user switches away from an existing destop using Fast User Switching.

4778 : This event is generated when a user reconnects to an existing Terminal Services session, or when a user switches to an existing desktop using Fast User Switching

users are connecting directly to 3389, not using a TS-gateway at the moment.

This behavior is consistent on different clients that we have, Full desktop is fine, RemoteAPP constantly disconnects.

The .rdp file used doesn't list any interesting parameters, aside from what application to launch, and where to find it.

Can someone explain to me how there can be a difference in behaviour between full desktop, and remoteapp ? since essentially they use the exact same client ?

Regards

Jeroen

Answer (score 2):

Solved,

This issue was solved by increasing the session timeout value for the RDP service on our Juniper SSG firewall.

remains odd that this was only affecting our remoteapp sessions however.

Comment: Definitely strange.  Question should have mentioned that there was a firewall between client and server!